# i can't switch between pages with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

today i am writing my latest project.
but i have a problem with react router.
when i want to switch page from navbar
it can't.
here is the demo >> https://zedjf.csb.app/
if you can pls help me solve this problem, any suggestion will be very helpful to improve my project.
thnx.

> github code: https://github.com/ennouri0maak/forslack

Comment: Hi, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example here in your question and include more specific details about what is or isn't working, steps to reproduce issue, and actual and expected results. Links to codesandboxes are great but they can be mutated or removed over time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate component for home page instead of replace the router.

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
      <div>
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/about" component={About} />
         <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
         <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
       </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

It may resolve your issue.

Ref: [Codebox Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-leftpad-b85ib)